# Finite Integral involving Bessel Function, $J_1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

Is there a closed form solution for the following integral

$$
\int_0^a dx \ x \ J_1(x) \ ,
$$
where $J_1(x)$ is a Bessel Function and $a>0$ is a finite real number?

Thanks.

Comment: Ask Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Thanks, @YvesDaoust, I don't know why I didn't check that myself in the first place. I am not familiar with Struve Functions, so if anyone has a different way of getting to the solution, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, according the Mathematica, is

$$
\int_0^a dx \ x \ J_1(x) = \frac{\pi a}{2} \left( H_0(a)J_1(a) - H_1(a)J_0(a) \right) \ .
$$

$H_n(x)$ is the [Struve Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StruveFunction.html).

Comment: For even $n$, you can get the integral $\int x J_n(x)\;dx$ not using Struve.